# Event listeners won't be called in IE -- what's wrong here?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, dgrid

**Technical context:**

- dojo 1.8.1
- dgrid 0.3.4-pre
- IE 10.0.9200

**Short version:**

I have some dojo/on events I'm listening too (from _WidgetBase), but they'll sometimes get called and sometimes don't. dgrid, pagination and IE are in the mix. What could be the problem?

**Details:**

I have this weird situation with a dgrid grid, and as much as I've tried, I have not been able to isolate the actual cause of the issue. I'll be as thorough as I can, but feel free to ask for more information.

I have a dgrid component that's using pagination and a combo box that has some values on which I will filter by. This is pretty much how it is set up (simplified, actual code references other modules and has stuff more modularized):

```
// GridContainerWidget
var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, CompoundColumns, Selection, Keyboard, Pagination], {
    selectionMode: "single",
    rowsPerPage: 20
});
var grid = new CustomGrid({
    deselectOnRefresh: false
}, domContainer);
```

The grid is later on bound to a JsonStore.

My filter is set up in the following way:

```
// SearchBarWidget
// inside a custom widget, inheriting from _WidgetBase
var self = this;
var statusCombo = new ComboBox({
    store: new Memory(/* data and labels */),
    onChange: function (selection) {
        self.emit("status_changed", self.getSomeData());
    }
}, comboDomContainer);
```

And back to the widget that encapsulates both the filter and the grid:

```
// GenericListWidget, contains both the SearchBarWidget and the GridContainerWidget
var self = this;
this._searchToolbar.on("status_changed", function (data) {
    // ... some "calibrations" ...
    self._grid.set("query", { newCriteria: "something" });
});
```

**This is where it gets weird:**

- Sometimes in IE `emit("status_changed")` will be called but the callback `on("status_changed")` won't be called. Some other times, emit will be called and the callback will be called too (expected).

  - This has to do with the pagination or the grid refresh somehow, but I've not been able to isolate the exact same steps that reproduce the issue
  - In digging deeper into this, I've seen IE reaches the point where it executes the following: (dojo/on, lines 314 to 322)

    ```
    var nativeEvent = target.ownerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    nativeEvent.initEvent(type /* "status_changed" */, !!event.bubbles /* true */, !!event.cancelable /* true */);
    // ... copies properties ...
    return target.dispatchEvent(nativeEvent) && nativeEvent; // returns true
    ```
  - I verified that the `remove()` call for the on hook is never being called
  - I verified that the DOM element on which events are being triggered and listened onto are actually the same, every time

My question is: how can I find the underlying issue and make sure that my on() callback gets called every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/379 which was fixed in dgrid 0.3.7.  To resolve the issue as it pertains to the paging controls in the Pagination extension, you will either need to update your version of dgrid or apply the changeset yourself.

This is due to a rather ridiculous and annoying IE bug present in IE9 and IE10 (fixed in IE11):

- https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/799780/ie10-addeventlistener-function-is-fired-by-a-different-event
- https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802397/ie9-ie10-events-can-be-sent-to-the-wrong-listeners

Comment: This seems likely the case. I will apply the changeset into the grid (since the size of my project does not allow me to upgrade easily), and since this issue seems to occur with events triggered from non-navigating anchors, my problem should go away. I'll be back with some results!

Comment: Took me a while, but applying the fix directly as a mixin did the trick. Thanks a lot!